# Are 'when' and 'by the time' interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, difference

I'd like to know whether '**when**' and '**by the time**' are interchangeable or not.

> 1. **When** your plane takes off, I will be back at home.
> 2. **By the time** your plane takes off, I will be back at home.

Comment: No, they have different definitions although they are close in meaning. Did you look them up in a dictionary.

Comment: See this related question, which may answer this for you: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21101/by-the-time-before